# Error at rosmake ccny_ground_station --rosdep-install

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to install the package ccny_ground_station.

On the command

$rosmake ccny_ground_station --rosdep-install

I get the error as below.

```
 make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
  [ 14%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/telemetry_demo.dir/src/telemetry_widgets.o
  In file included from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/ground_station.cpp:34:
  **/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/include/ground_station/ground_station.h:55:32: error: asctec_msgs/Height.h: No such file or directory**

  In file included from /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/ground_station.cpp:34:
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/include/ground_station/ground_station.h:103: error: ‘Height’ in namespace ‘asctec_msgs’ does not name a type
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/ground_station.cpp:76: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/ground_station.cpp:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/ground_station.cpp:76: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token
  make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/groundstation.dir/src/ground_station.o] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/groundstation.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/telemetry_demo

  **CMakeFiles/telemetry_demo.dir/src/telemetry_widgets.o: In function `main':
  /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/src/telemetry_widgets.cpp:373: undefined reference to `g_thread_init'**

  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/telemetry_demo] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/telemetry_demo.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_ground_station/ground_station/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ground_station written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/robot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110616-191251/ground_station/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ground_station [FAIL] [ 5.80 seconds ]                                                                                              
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ground_station. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                                            
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                                                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Built 35 packages with 1 failures.                                                                                                               
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                                                                                                      
[ rosmake ] /home/robot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110616-191251
```

---

I guess the error is because of missing file asctec_msgs/Height.h. I even found a ticket related the issue. But no solution.
http://robotics.ccny.cuny.edu/trac/ticket/35

Other than this I get one more error of " undefined reference to `g_thread_init "

I am using cturtle on ubuntu 9.10. I am trying to use the ground station tool for the quadrotor I am building.

Thank you for your help.

-Suraj Swami

http://sites.google.com/site/surajswamiworkspace/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10282/error-at-rosmake-ccny_ground_station---rosdep-install/) by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2011-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just update `ccny_ground_station` to the point where it compiles, if you download the latest version (from git) of our other stacks.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) on 2011-06-17**:
I can confirm it compiles successfully on diamond-back. Make sure dependencies have been also cloned, for example the "mav_tools". Then, you could just type: $ rosmake ground_station --rosdep-install

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would just stay away from the ccny_ground_station at the moment. The package has not been maintained for about a year. We'll look into it, but for now I would suggest you something else such as [qgroundcontrol](http://qgroundcontrol.org/) although it does not seem to be ROSified just yet.

---

Originally posted by [ubuntuslave](https://answers.ros.org/users/631/ubuntuslave/) with karma: 347 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ss_robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/348/ss_robotics/) on 2011-06-17**:
Thanks for the update. I could get it working. But I had to make one more change to get the rosmake running without any error.